# change font color of selected item in navbar

Tags: html, css

Im trying to change the font of the selected item in navbar using the visited function in css but it doesn't work to my app. Is there any other solution that I can use? here is my current script:

```
 <style>
    .navbar-header:visited {
        color: red;
    }
</style>


 <html>
 <body>

 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container" style="border-style: groove;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Main", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", style = "color: #8C8D8E;" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Name List", "Name", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", style = "color: #8C8D8E;" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", style = "color: #8C8D8E;" }     
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 </html>
 </body>
```

Any suggestion/comments TIA

Answer (score 3):

The particular styling you're trying to use shouldn't be used on your header, it should be used on the anchor tags contained within it.

Therefore, you only need to make a small change :

```
.navbar-header a:visited {
        color: red;
    }
```

This is because your DIV doesn't have an href, so it can't be visited or not. It's the anchor tags that are controlling your page redirects.

Additionally, because your creating your action links and then putting inline-styling within it, that is prioritized over [CSS external links.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

You would have to remove the styling from your action creation, and you could solve your problem by putting that same styling in a class instead.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Main", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

Above, you can see I've removed the styling as an example. Then you would simply need to add the following CSS.

```
.navbar-brand {
        color: #8C8D8E;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to modify it using your suggested but it still the same result. nothing change when I clicked other link

Comment: @Rockn'Roll This is because you have inline-styling, which is prioritized over external styling. I have edited my answer to explain this.